# css @media screen width doesn't work

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I used media queries similar to what's advised [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/), to create a page that is dependent of screen size.

The media query with both an upper and lower limit `@media only screen and (min-width: 601) and (max-width: 1249px)`
 does not work. What's wrong?

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffrv703e/5/) with my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a unit of measurement to the `min-width`:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1249px) {
```

Here is the fiddle (after adding colors just to make it easier to test the queries): http://jsfiddle.net/ffrv703e/7/